# Не отображаются записи из SQL таблицы в WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server, wpf-datagrid

Никаких ошибок, к базе данных подключается исправно. Просто не выводит записи из таблицы. Если есть идеи, буду благодарен.

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridEmployee" Height="260">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Фамилия"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Отчество"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Дата рождения"  
                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource DateTemplate}"  
                    CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource EditingDateTemplate}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Телефон"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Электронная почта"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Должность"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid>
```

.cs страницы:

```
string connectionString; SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable employeeTable;

    public PageEmployee()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // получаем строку подключения из app.config 
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WpfApp1.Properties.Settings.TitlePersonEntities"].ConnectionString;
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
        employeeTable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(employeeTable);
            DataGridEmployee.ItemsSource = employeeTable.DefaultView;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null) connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

[image: тут должны быть записи)]

Comment: Поставьте точку отладки на строку `employeeTable = new DataTable();` и посмотрите под отладкой, читаются ли данные. А то может у вас не доходит до этой строки или что ещё.

Comment: как выглядит ваша `connectionString`? У вас там в БД данные точно есть?

Comment: Да, в бд данные точно есть, к бд подключается. (пробовал менять строку подключения - выдает ошибку). Я, кажется нашел проблему благодаря @AK . При загрузке страницы не срабатывает PageLoaded, я на всякий случай еще message box приписал, он не выводится. А почему не знаю:( Щас буду пытаться разобраться.

Comment: В xaml это событие назначьте окну `Loaded="Page_Loaded"`

Comment: @aepot спасибо! :)